# How to press a component and it rotates 180 degrees in react native?

Tags: react-native, animation

I have a Pressable component and inside it I have an icon. I want to press it and rotate it 180 degrees, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So to do this you must take use of the Animated library from react-native.
In which you make animated values and make functions to update them. Here's a full sample of you want (https://snack.expo.dev/@heytony01/grumpy-pretzel) and below is the explantion.

**First import the library and make an Animated value**

```js
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Animated,TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';

const spinValue = React.useState(new Animated.Value(0))[0]; // Makes animated value
```

**Next define functions to change the value**

```js
 // When button is pressed in, make spinValue go through and up to 1
 const onPressIn = () => {
     Animated.spring(spinValue, {
         toValue: 1,
         useNativeDriver: true,
     }).start();
 };

 // When button is pressed out, make spinValue go through and down to 0
 const onPressOut = () => {
     Animated.spring(spinValue, {
         toValue: 0,
         useNativeDriver: true,
     }).start();
 };
```

**The tricky part is that in order to rotate in react-native you need to pass "0deg" or "12deg" etc..**

```js
<View style={{
        transform: [
          { rotate: "45deg" },
        ]
      }}>
 </View>
```

**So what you do is you interpolate the animated value to "0deg" to "360deg"**

```js
// spinDeg will be between '0deg' and '360deg' based on what spinValue is 
const spinDeg = spinValue.interpolate({
      useNativeDriver: true,
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
  })
```

**Lastly you pass in the spinDeg into your button and your done**

```js
 // The animated style for scaling the button within the Animated.View
    const animatedScaleStyle = {
        transform: [{rotate: spinDeg}]
    };

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback
             
              onPress={()=>{}}
              onPressIn={onPressIn}
              onPressOut={onPressOut}
          >
          <View style={{justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center",backgroundColor:"lightgray",padding:15,borderRadius:20}}>
              <Text>PRESS ME</Text>
              <Animated.View style={[styles.iconContainer, animatedScaleStyle]}>
                        <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" />
              </Animated.View>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    );
```

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, in my case I just need the onPressIn part. But the animation only works once. Where do I update, so when the user clicks the second time the animation runs again?

Comment: You probably need to set the value back to what it was from the start when the animation is done